# JavaScript - Overlay button on video

Tags: javascript, html, button, video, overlay

I'm able to play a video and have it pause after 5 seconds. When it pauses at 5 seconds, I would like for a button to appear in the middle of the screen. When the button is clicked, I would like for the currentTime to be set at 20 seconds, for the button to disappear, and for the video to play at 20 seconds. I'm not sure how to execute this.

This is what I have so far:

.js

```
var video = document.getElementById("myvid");
video.addEventListener("timeupdate", function(){
    if(this.currentTime >= 5) {
        this.pause(); 
        //need to call for the button to appear in the video screen. overlay?
        //when the button is clicked, call the skip() function
        //button needs to disappear 
    }
});

function skip(){
    video.currentTime = 20;
    video.play();
}
```

.html

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <video id="myvid" width="320" height="240" controls>
        <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>

    //would i put an onclick button here?
</div>
```

Since it's a button for now, would I even need .css?

Comment: <button onclick="skip()">skip 20</button>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a click handler to the button with `onclick="function()"`

we will set its style to display none as you want it to be hidden to begin with

we'll select in the javascript call it `button` and when you pause the video we'll set it to be visible.

```js
var video = document.getElementById("myvid");
var button = document.querySelector("button");
var firstRun = true;
video.addEventListener("timeupdate", function(){
    if(this.currentTime >= 5 && firstRun) {
        this.pause();
        firstRun = false;
        button.style = "display: block";
    }
});

function skip(){
    video.currentTime = 20;
    video.play();
    button.style = "";
}
```

```css
button {
  display: none; 
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <video id="myvid" width="320" height="240" controls>
        <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>

    <button onclick="skip()">skip</button>
</div>
```

Comment: delay and button work, but it did not continue playing for me.   Also second time, it just paused.  just FYI, I think all that can be fixed.

Comment: @JoeWarner This works, thanks!! Is there a way to overlay the button onto the video instead of having it be outside??